# count unique values in groups pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe like this:

```
data = {'id': [1,1,1,2,2,3],
        'value': ['a','a','a','b','b','c'],
        'obj_id': [1,2,3,3,3,4]
}
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['id','value','obj_id'])
```

I would like to get the unique counts of `obj_id` groupby `id` and `value`:

```
1 a 3
2 b 1
3 c 1
```

But when I do:

```
result=df.groupby(['id','value'])['obj_id'].nunique().reset_index(name='obj_counts')
```

the result I got was:

```
1 a 2
1 a 1
2 b 1
3 c 1
```

so the first two rows with same `id` and `value` don't group together.

How can I fix this? Many thanks!

Comment: For me your solution working nice

Comment: Check your two a , may have white-space

Comment: oh yes! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me your solution working nice with sample data.

Like mentioned @YOBEN_S in comments is possible problem traling whitespeces, then solution is add [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
data = {'id': [1,1,1,2,2,3],
        'value': ['a ','a','a','b','b','c'],
        'obj_id': [1,2,3,3,3,4]
}
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['id','value','obj_id'])

df['value'] = df['value'].str.strip()
df = df.groupby(['id','value'])['obj_id'].nunique().reset_index(name='obj_counts')
print (df)
   id value  obj_counts
0   1     a           3
1   2     b           1
2   3     c           1
```

Comment: you are correct! there's white space. your code works for me now. thanks so much!